# Socket.getOutputStream() on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, sockets, outputstream

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.OutputStream java.net.Socket.getOutputStream()' on a null object reference

Before you mark down this, I am very new to this, I have tried to search on ways to solve this before posting but I can't seem to find a solution. I hope you understand.

I get this error when i run the on change listener.

```
seekbarbrightness.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
      @Override
      public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekbarbrightness, int progress, boolean b) {
           if(b==true) {
                tblumens.setText(String.valueOf(progress) + " Lumens");
                try {
                     socket.getOutputStream().write(String.valueOf(progress).getBytes());

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                      }
           }
     }
});
```

I run the below code in the `onCreate` method.

```
class ClientThread implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);
            check = "fail";
            socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);
            check = "success";

        } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

What is the problem? Is it because my socket connection is not initialized properly? (Also, i have not got my server running yet, however, the catch would show an error won't it?)

I've tried to use a if `socket.isConnected()` function then do the try and catch, but it makes no difference..

Please help! I've searched for many tutorials and arrived at these codes for the socket client connection.

Comment: `socket` is null, obviously, and obviously this is because the connect failed. `Socket.isConnected()` can't possibly help, as you don't have a `Socket`.

Comment: ah, is there a way to avoid the crash? Like after the connect failed maybe the phone can just let me know about connection failure through a toast and not let it crash when i move my seekbar?

Comment: It *did* let you know. There was a `ConnectException`. Or else you have a programming bug. Have you considered testing for `socket == null`?

Comment: omg i did a if(socket!=null) and yes now my app stops crashing on failure to connect. Thanks man, looks like i misunderstood and kept using socket.isConnected() instead of checking if it is not null. Thank you so much. Maybe i should change the question title.

Comment: Well there's another aspect to this. The user shouldn't be able to press UI buttons unless there is a connection. You should disable the parts of the UI that require a connection until there is one.

Comment: Oh yes! Come to think of it, that should be the way. I will modify my codes accordingly. Awesome! Thanks man

Answer (score -1):

Did you accept the socket connection with the client?

```
socket.accept();
```

I think your `socket.getOutputStream()` might be null in setOnSeekBarChangeListener

Comment: This *is* the client; his socket is a `Socket`, which doesn't have an `accept()` method; and the result of `ServerSocket.accept()` needs to be stored somewhere.

Comment: And `Socket.getOutputStream()` doesn't return null.